# Azure IoT Hub and MRAA on Intel Edison

Tags: c, azure, makefile, iot, intel-edison

Currently I have to send sensor data I receive on my Intel Edison to Azure IoT Hub. I have the samples from IoT working and the sensor receiving data but connecting the two isn't really working out.

I tried merging the code from the sensor in the sample from **Azure IoT hub** (this one: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/blob/master/c/iothub_client/samples/iothub_client_sample_http/iothub_client_sample_http.c)

But this file has a complex make file and I cant seem to include my **MRAA** pin library ([Low Level Skeleton Library for IO Communication on GNU/Linux platforms](https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/mraa)).

Is there a way to include the MRAA library or a simple IoT sample I can easily modify without this huge and complex make file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added "mraa" to the target_link_libraries() part in the CmakeLists.txt file.

This added the library to the file!